# Remove all duplicate values from a vector?

Tags: c++

Input:

```
1 1 2 2 3
```

Desired Output:

```
3
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   vector<int> v;
   vector<int>::iterator it;
   // input variables
   int input, a, arr[10000];
   // input 
   cin >> input;
   // comment all your loops, etc
   for(int i = 0; i < input ; i++){
       cin >> a;
       arr[i] = a;
       v.push_back(a);
   }

   for(int j = 0; j < input; j++){
      int ch1 = arr[j];
      for(int i = 0;i < input; i++){
         if(i == j){
         }
         else{
            if(ch1 == arr[i]){
            v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), ch1),v.end());
            }
            else{
            }
         }
      }
   }

   for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
       cout << *it;
   }

  return 0;
}
```

`erase()` is not working here.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is not a debugging service. What do you mean your erase is "not working"? Also format your code.

Comment: First of all, your `v` counter in `for` loop shadows `v` vector on function level; that is why `v.erase` is not accessible. Second, if you are allowed to use another container to detect duplicates, then why not just export the entire `std::vector<int>` into a `std::set<int>` while watching the result of each insertion, and adding all detected duplicated to yet another `std::set<int>`, and finally exporting the first set back to `std::vector<int>` except values in second `std::set<int>`?

Comment: You're not using the _STL_, I removed the tag. Read the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info) of [tag:stl], it's not referring to what you think it actually is!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you define two variables with name v.

```
vector<int>v;
for(int v=0...
```

So you basically hide your vector with an int and the compiler tries to call erase() for int, which gives you error.

Just change the name of one of these variables.

Comment: where is this other variable with the same name ?